# Insert into sql temp table with a default column

Tags: t-sql, insert, temp-tables

I'm creating a temp table in tsql with 1 column having a default value as below:

```
DECLARE @MyTable Table (MyName varchar(40) Primary Key not null, Updated SmallInt NULL DEFAULT 0)
```

When I run an insert statement, I get an error that "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.".  But the second column is suppose to get the default value and I do not want to specify that.  Any workarounds?

```
INSERT @MyTable 
VALUES ('Value1'),
       ('Value2')
```

Comment: What is that INSERT statement you posted?

Comment: Jenny: I'm not sure I understand your question, but the INSERT statement are populating the temp table with values.  That is the statement that causes the error.

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of this syntax.

Comment: @user1208908 you have 2 columns MyName primary key, and a Updated, that a table has a primary key it doesn't mean that the column will be populated. only Identity columns get populated automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the columns that get a value and leave away those that do not:

```
INSERT @MyTable (MyName) VALUES ('Value1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a column list

```
INSERT @MyTable (MyName)
VALUES ('Value1'),('Value2')
```

Or the DEFAULT keyword as per @AlexK's answer

Using a column list allows the table definition to change somewhat (say adding another column with default) without changing the INSERTS

Answer (score 1):

Check your syntax - it looks like you have too many opening and closing parens, and that's why you're encountering that error. I think it should look more like this:

```
INSERT INTO @MyTable 
VALUES ('Value1','Value2')
```

or, as others have mentioned, you can try specifying the columns, too:

```
INSERT INTO @MyTable (col1, col2)
VALUES ('Value1','Value2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `DEFAULT` keyword;

```
INSERT @MyTable 
VALUES ('Value1', DEFAULT),
       ('Value2', DEFAULT)
```